# How can I write a program in Python Dictionary that prints repeated keys values?

Tags: python-3.x

## This is my INPUT:

`dic1 = {'a':'USA', 'b':'Canada', 'c':'France'}
dic2 = {'c':'Italy', 'd':'Norway', 'e':'Denmark'}
dic3 = {'e':'Finland', 'f':'Japan', 'g':'Germany’}`

## I want output something like below:

`{'g': 'Germany', 'e': [‘Denmark’,’Finland'], 'd': 'Norway', 'c': ['Italy’,'France', 'f': 'Japan', 'b': 'Canada', 'a': 'USA'}`

Answer (score 0):

That is programing - you think the steps you need to get to your desired results, and write code to perform these steps, one at a time.

A funciton like this can do it:

```
def merge_dicts(*args):
    merged = {}
    for dct in args:
       for key, value in dct.items():
           if key not in merged:
               merged[key] = []
           merged[key].append(value)
    return merged
```